# Utility shows website visitors information, any idea?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-analytics

I need some code which shows my website visitors information such as, Ip, visiting time etc, and possibly send this information to my pre-defined email. Do you guys have any  good suggestion?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all of that stuff in the $_SERVER variable in [php](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)